# Performance impact on comparing INT to TINYINT

Tags: sql, sql-server, memory-management, casting, database-administration

I am working on some legacy tables that have a column defined as INT which should ideally be a TINYINT instead because it just has some lookup values ranging from 0-10.

I am writing an SP in which I will have a temp variable to compare with this column. for example:

***tblLkpCode (Code INT, Name CHAR(1))***

```
Code Name
0   A
1   B
2   C
3   D
4   E
5   F
6   G
7   H
8   I
9   J
10  K
```

In my SP I have code like:

```
DECLARE @lkpCode TINYINT = 5    --Should I define this as INT or TINYINT?

SELECT Name FROM tblLkpCode WHERE Code = @lkpCode
```

I wish to know in such scenarios where my variable can be TINYINT, should I define them as TINYINT or since the target column with which I am comparing this variable is of INT type, so I should define my variable as INT too.

If I define my variable as INT, it will take unnecessarily more space in memory than TINYINT but if I use TINYINT, it may cause typecasting in comparison.

Although I understand that given the amount of memory and processing power we have nowadays, using either of these two will probably not make any performance difference at all.

But I am still curious to find what is recommended or good practice in this case?

Furthermore, Imagine if we are doing this back in the 1980s which one here is more efficient and why?

Comment: I'd let safety trump all other considerations and use `int`.

Comment: In general, an optimization between `tinyint` and `int` is a waste of time.  It might sometimes be useful in a very space-constrained environment, but otherwise, worry about more important considerations.